# How to use NPM scoped packages for a Cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, npm, cordova-plugins

we are developing a couple of NPM packages under the same organization:

```
@aerogearservices/core
@aerogearservices/core-rn
@aerogearservices/core-cordova
```

Where `core-cordova` is a Cordova plugin, installed via dependencies (read more about [scoped packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope)).

Relevant files:

App's package.json

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@aerogearservices/core-cordova": "1.0.0",
    ...
  },
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {},
    "platforms": ["ios", "android"]
  }
}
```

Plugin's package.json

```
{
  "name": "@aerogearservices/core-cordova",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  ...
  "cordova": {
    "id": "aerogearservices-core-cordova",
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aerogearservices/core": "1.0.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "cordovaDependencies": {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Plugin's plugin.xml

...
    ...
    Apache 2.0

```
<platform name="android">
    <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*"> 
        ...
    </config-file>

    <source-file 
        ...
    />
</platform>
```

The plugin really does nothing yet, I am just trying to install it in my app but when I run `cordova platform add android` I get this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin "@aerogearservices". Please try adding it again.
```

The problem is that Cordova installs the plugin under `myApp/plugins/aerogearservices/core-cordova` so that it is looking for `plugin.xml` at the wrong location.

[image]

How do scoped packages and cordova plugins work together? Is there any workaround to this **without renaming the plugin**?

Comment: Patch Cordova and submit PR?

Answer (score 7):

It might not be the slution to your problem, but I ended up having problems creating a cordova plugin published in a scoped npm registry, and this is how I managed to fix it:

Plugin's config.xml should not mention the scope:

```
<plugin id="cordova-plugin-myplugin" ...>
<name>cordova-plugin-myplugin</name>
```

On the other hand, plugin's package.json should mention it:

```
"name": "@scope/cordova-plugin-myplugin",
"cordova": {
    "id": "@scope/cordova-plugin-myplugin",
    "platforms": [
        "android",
        "windows",
        "ios"
        ]
    },
```

now, I have no problem using

```
cordova plugin add @scope/cordova-plugin-myplugin
```

I hope this might actually help someone

Answer (score 3):

You may have already solved this problem, but cordova@10 can handle scoped plugins just fine.

Plugin's config.xml should mention the scope:

```
<plugin id="cordova-plugin-myplugin" ...>
<name>@scope/cordova-plugin-myplugin</name>
```

And, plugin's package.json should mention it:

```
"name": "@scope/cordova-plugin-myplugin",
"cordova": {
    "id": "@scope/cordova-plugin-myplugin",
    "platforms": [
        "android",
        "windows",
        "ios"
        ]
    },
```

now, I have no problem using

```
cordova plugin add @scope/cordova-plugin-myplugin
```